# Hide out of stock products on specific category archives In Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to write some code that hides out of stock items only on certain category pages.

I tried to make a pre posts hook like so:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','filter_out_of_stock_discs');

function filter_out_of_stock_discs($query){

    if($query->query_vars["post_type"] == "product"){
        //...
    }
}
```

I can see in debugger this never gets hit as no query has query var of product post type.

I also tried adding this to my taxonomy product page before the loop is called:

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->set("meta_query", array(
                array(
                        'key' => '_stock_status',
                        'value' => 'instock'
                ),
                array(
                        'key' => '_backorders',
                        'value' => 'no'
                ),
        )
);
```

But that doesn't change anything.

How can I intercept the query to modify whether it checks for stock status or not?

Comment: Did you enable debugging?

Comment: debugging is enabled and i have stepped through code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woocommerce has their own filter.  This worked for me:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query','filter_out_of_stock_prod', 10, 2);

function filter_out_of_stock_prod($q, $wc_query){

    $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => '_stock_status',
        'value' => 'instock',
        'compare' => '='
    );

    $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
```